# Why is rails using the .js.coffee extension for coffeescript files when they cannot contain javascript code anyway?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, coffeescript

I found that to be rather misleading as I thought it suggest that such files could include a mixture of both javascript and coffeescript code. Is there something very fundamental that I am missing?

Comment: They do the same for CSS files: .css.scss

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's a common practice in Rails for templates to have extensions like `.js.coffee`, `.html.erb`, `.html.haml`, etc.

If I remember correctly Rails interprets these extensions as `.[format].[builder]` and uses that knowledge to do two things:

1. find proper template by `[format]` value comparing it with acceptable formats listed in the request's `Accept` header;
2. find appropriate template processor by `[builder]` value to parse your template.

Comment: I guess this is the fundamental thing I was missing: I started off with html.erb files and they contain both html and erb code, which led to my current understanding

Comment: @KL-7 - thank you. i have a separate but related question: why is there .coffee files and .js.coffee files in my javascript folder? what is the difference between them?

Answer (score 1):

And you can include plain javascript if you use backticks.

Something like `` `function(){ do something };` `` would work.